# Can I use Pushkit to wake app up in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, websocket, voip, pushkit

I have an app that needs to keep TCP Socket alive. As we know as app transits into background or the app gets terminated by iOS, The socket would get killed too.
But, I didn't want that -I want to keep socket alive. So i used pushkit and VOIP to keep the socket alive. I do the ping-pong within the app and server to check the socket is alive and as soon as the app doesn't send ping back for several second. I send a voip trigger from backend which would be received in

```
- (void)pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials:(PKPushCredentials *)pushCredentials forType:(PKPushType)type {
}
```

Will that work? Is this the right way?

Can I use Silent Push Notification to implement this? The iOS app would receive a silent push from server as soon as the ping-pong is not received for n seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Not a chance. When your app receives a VoIP push notification, it MUST show the CallKit UI as soon as possible. Failure to do so means your app won't receive VoIP pushes very soon.

The right way is to stop sending pings in the background and not using up the device's battery.

Comment: Can I use SIlent Push Notifications to achieve this?

Comment: I understand that you should drain the device's battery at least as possible, but my opinion is that if it serves the use case, it should be possible anyway. It is then the users choice to use the app or not. Maybe this is not a popular opinion.